# SSRS - export with a toggle

Tags: reporting-services, export, report

I have created a report and put it into RS, when exporting there is a toggle button to see the rest of the columns.

This only happens when exporting the report. Is there a way to remove to toggle button besizes removing columns from the report design?

Thanks

Comment: Resolved by removing the ToggleItem property

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by removing the ToggleItem property